# How to count Users by Pathology using DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an issue to find an alternative way to count Users who suffer a pathology (a count with a group by)
the issue is I prefer not to make a for loop on pathologies to count that, and I'de like if I could get your advice.
here's some pieces of code I have :

User Entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Hospitalisation", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $hospitalisations;
```

Hospitalisation Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pathologie", inversedBy="hospitalisations")
 */
private $pathologie;
```

Pathology Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Hospitalisation", mappedBy="pathologie")
 */
private $hospitalisations;
```

What I have to do is to count how many users suffers of each pathologie in the database.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
Here's the solution i've come up with:

```
$result = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("
            SELECT p.id, p.nom, COUNT(DISTINCT u) as nbUsers , COUNT(DISTINCT i) as nbImported 
                FROM AcmeDemoBundlePathologie p
                left JOIN p.importedUsers i
                left JOIN p.hospitalisations h
                left JOIN h.user u

                GROUP BY p.id, p.nom
        ")
        ->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Create a custom repository class **PathologieRepository**

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Add this (not tested):

```
public function countUsers($pathologieID)
{
    $result = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("
            SELECT COUNT(u) as c FROM YourMainBundle:Users u
                JOIN u.hospitalisations h
                JOIN h.pathologies p
                WHERE
                    p.id = :pathologie
        ")
        ->setParameter('pathologie', $pathologieID)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getSingleResult();
    return $result['c'];
}
```

If you want do this in twig like (pseudo):

```
for pathologie as p
       print p.countUsers(p.id)
```

You have to create a method in your pathologie entity class. But you cannot use entity manager in entity classes (you can by using a hack but this is not recommended). So you have to use loops to count the users.

```
public function getUserCount()
{
    $hospitalisations = $this->getHospitalisations();
    $counter = 0;

    foreach ($hospitalisations as $h)
    {
        $counter += count($h->getUsers());
    }

    return $counter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in your logic you missed the relations, User -> OneToMany -> Hospitalisation /
Hospitalisation -> ManyToOne -> User /
Pathology -> OneToMany -> Hospitalisation /
Hospitalisation -> ManyToOne -> Pathology